# Alexa skills: HSL plays, but no sound

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, http-live-streaming, alexa-skills-kit

Well Hello There,

I am using the "AudioPlayer" of the "Alexa Skill Kit" to stream a HLS audio format URL. I am receiving no errors from the AWS Lambda, Silent Echo, and from the Developer Portal. I am testing by using the Silent Echo.

Alexa is able to play MP3 formatted URLs fine. Silent Echo would play my HLS URL, but I can't hear anything. I also tested other HLS URLs, listed below, I also can't hear anything from them. However, they do work when you play it with the VLC software.

My HLS URL: https://cpdc101-lh.akamaihd.net/i/ISNCPDCMB1_1@314337/master.m3u8

Other HLS:

ehttps://c4.prod.playlists.ihrhls.com/3379/playlist.m3u8

ehttp://radioitaliasmi-lh.akamaihd.net/i/radioitaliasmi_1@329643/master.m3u8

http://radiom2o-lh.akamaihd.net/i/RadioM2o_Live_1@42518/master.m3u8

Could someone please test my HLS as well? Wonder if it is just me or maybe Silent Echo won't play it.

Lambda Function code:

```js
var lastPlayedByUser = {};
var streamURL = "https://cpdc101-lh.akamaihd.net/i/ISNCPDCMB1_1@314337/master.m3u8";


exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var player = new SidRothPlayer(event, context);
    player.handle();
};

var SidRothPlayer = function (event, context) {
    this.event = event;
    this.context = context;
};

SidRothPlayer.prototype.handle = function () {
    var requestType = this.event.request.type;
    var userId = this.event.context ? this.event.context.System.user.userId : this.event.session.user.userId;

   if (requestType === "LaunchRequest") {
        this.play(streamURL, 0);

    } else  if (requestType === "IntentRequest") {
        var intent = this.event.request.intent;
        if (intent.name === "Play") {
            this.play(streamURL, 0);

        } else if (intent.name === "AMAZON.PauseIntent") {
            this.stop();

        } else if (intent.name === "AMAZON.ResumeIntent") {
            var lastPlayed = this.loadLastPlayed(userId);
            var offsetInMilliseconds = 0;
            if (lastPlayed !== null) {
                offsetInMilliseconds = lastPlayed.request.offsetInMilliseconds;
            }

            this.play(streamURL, offsetInMilliseconds);
        }
    } else if (requestType === "AudioPlayer.PlaybackStopped") {
        this.saveLastPlayed(userId, this.event);
        this.context.succeed(true);
    }
};


 SidRothPlayer.prototype.play = function (audioURL, offsetInMilliseconds) {
    var response = {
        version: "1.0",
        response: {
            shouldEndSession: true,
            directives: [
                {
                    type: "AudioPlayer.Play",
                    playBehavior: "REPLACE_ALL", 
                    audioItem: {
                        stream: {
                            url: audioURL,
                            token: "0", 
                            expectedPreviousToken: null, 
                            offsetInMilliseconds: offsetInMilliseconds
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    this.context.succeed(response);
};


SidRothPlayer.prototype.stop = function () {
    var response = {
        version: "1.0",
        response: {
            shouldEndSession: true,
            directives: [
                {
                    type: "AudioPlayer.Stop"
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    this.context.succeed(response);
};

SidRothPlayer.prototype.saveLastPlayed = function (userId, lastPlayed) {
    lastPlayedByUser[userId] = lastPlayed;
};

SidRothPlayer.prototype.loadLastPlayed = function (userId) {
    var lastPlayed = null;
    if (userId in lastPlayedByUser) {
        lastPlayed = lastPlayedByUser[userId];
    }
    return lastPlayed;
};
```

Thank you,

Jackson

Answer (score 0):

Silent Echo and Echosim does not support HLS.  One must have an Echo Machine to test HLS stream.

I just tested my code on an Echo Machine and it works.